# ListView item with dynamic layout(Imageview, TextView)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

im creating an ExpandableListView where childitem look like the image below
[image]

the flags in this layout are dynamic the data returns only the number of flags needed with the text and imagepath (ie: number of teams participating in the tournament)

now what i am doing is i have created a layout that has a HorizontalScrollView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:id="@+id/tournament_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/form_ico2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ICC World Twenty20 2014"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/subheading"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/tournament_name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tournament_image" />

</RelativeLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CREATE TEAM"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/tournament_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/flags_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tournament_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and another layout with ImageView and TextView
flag_with_text_layout.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/flag_india"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="IND"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

i inflate the layout on runtime and load the image and text(ie flag and team name)
this is the method i use to inflate the layout

```
for(TeamModel m : tourn.getTeamModels()){
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"team name:"+m.getName());

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flag_with_text_layout,null);
                ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
                TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);

                loader.DisplayImage(m.getImage(),img);
                text.setText(m.getName());

                flagsLayout.addView(view);
            }
```

now the problem is that inflating so many views for flag and team name is a very heavy process on runtime which i have to do inside getChildView method and for this reason my app stops responding and close without any exception or dialogue because the phone gets out of memory

i have tried to created the views in another method and put it inside an ArrayList and just get the layout in the getChildView method instead of creating it on scroll...

but still it is a very heavy process to do..can any1 help me and tell me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `loader.DisplayImage(m.getImage(),img);` line is fetching image from server in UI thread. If that is the case you need to get the image in a background thread and in the mean time show some dummy image until the image is fetched. You can use UniversalImageLoader too for loading images : -

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader